# What is the difference between `PG.connect` and `PG::Connection.open` in the Ruby 'pg' gem?

Tags: ruby, pg

From the [pg module doc](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html), it seems like the right way to connect to a PG db is to use:

```
conn = PG::Connection.open(dbname: 'test')
```

However, I find [other examples](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlruby/) online which make use of the `PG.connect` method instead:

```
conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'testdb', user: 'janbodnar', password: 'pswd37')
```

Is there a difference between these two ways of connecting to a postgresql database? If yes, what is it? Is one way better than the other? What are the drawbacks / advantages of each method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for the PG module itself](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG.html), you can see that `PG.connect` is a "convenience alias" for `PG::Connection.new`:

```
def self::connect( *args )
  return PG::Connection.new( *args )
end
```

From the [source code of `PG::Connection`](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/ext/pg_connection.c), it's also clear that `PG::Connection.open` is an alias of `PG::Connection.new`:

```
void
init_pg_connection()
{
    …
    SINGLETON_ALIAS(rb_cPGconn, "open", "new");
    …
}
```

So, all three are actually identical in terms of how they connect to the database. `PG.connect` adds the cost of one extra method call, since it internally calls `PG::Connection.new`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Somehow I did not see it in the PG module documentation, my bad, should have read the doc more carefully.

Comment: Or maybe there shouldn't be three different ways of doing exactly the same!